# ExitButtonHandler is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

Tags: java

Ok so i have this rather simple code although it keeps giving me this error message.  I have tried various different solutions through google but i cannot seem to figure it out.  I show where the error message is happening.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.lang.*;

public class Project4 extends JFrame
{


    private JLabel InCDAmount, YearTMature, CDInRate, EndBalance;

    private JTextField InCDAmountTF, YearTMatureTF, CDInRateTF, EndBalanceTF;

    private JButton calculateB, exitB;

    private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;
    private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

    private static int WIDTH = 400;
    private static int HEIGHT = 300;

    public Project4()
    {
    InCDAmount = new JLabel("Initial CD Amount", SwingConstants.LEFT);

    YearTMature = new JLabel("Years to Maturity", SwingConstants.LEFT);

    CDInRate = new JLabel("CD Intrest Rate", SwingConstants.LEFT);

    EndBalance = new JLabel("Ending Balance", SwingConstants.LEFT);


    InCDAmountTF = new JTextField(10);
    YearTMatureTF = new JTextField(10);
    CDInRateTF = new JTextField(10);

    calculateB = new JButton ("Calculate");
    cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
    calculateB.addActionListener(cbHandler);

    exitB = new JButton("Exit");
    ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
    exitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);

    setTitle("ACME Bank Certificate Of Deposit Calculator");

    Container pane = getContentPane();

    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));

    pane.add(InCDAmount);
    pane.add(InCDAmountTF);
    pane.add(YearTMature);
    pane.add(YearTMatureTF);
    pane.add(CDInRate);
    pane.add(CDInRateTF);
    pane.add(EndBalance);
    pane.add(EndBalanceTF);

    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
     double InCDAmount, YearTMature, CDInRate, EndBalance;

     InCDAmount = Double.parseDouble(InCDAmountTF.getText());
     YearTMature = Double.parseDouble(YearTMatureTF.getText());
     CDInRate = Double.parseDouble(CDInRateTF.getText());
     EndBalance = InCDAmount + YearTMature + CDInRate;

     EndBalanceTF.setText("" + EndBalance);
     }
  }
```

Right here is where i am having the issue.

```
  private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
```

it gives me the error message

ExitButtonHandler is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

```
private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
     public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
        System.exit(0);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Project4 rectObject = new Project4();
     }
}
```

Comment: The error message seems as clear as it can. You're not overring actionPerformed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e)
                   ^^
```

should be changed to

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

---

Next time, the use of the annotation `@Override` may help you with these kind of issues.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

It'll throw an error if the method is not a correct override.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Works fine now!